# How to know if (and when) a shutdown occurred due to power outage

Tags: macos, shutdown, power-management, console

I have a Mac in a remote location that operates as a server.

It's configured (from Energy Management) to automatically power up in case of blackout as the power comes back.

How can I tell if a power outage has happened (and the mac self-restarted later) and when ?

I guess I can inspect the console, but what should I search for?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get to Terminal on your remote machine, just type `uptime`
This won't, of course, tell you why it was last restarted, but when.

Comment: Yes, this is one solution. But uptime is reset also if I (or someone else managing the server) gracefully restart the machine. If that was, let's say, 30 days ago it's hard to remember...